# Confusion regarding converting recursion to iteration using stack

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have a big confusion on what is meant by the general method of converting recursive functions (tail and non tail) to iterative ones using stack. I made this simple example to illustrate the point:

```
int sigma1(int n) {
  if(n == 0) 
    return 0;
  else 
    return n + sigma1(n-1);
}
```

which of the following versions reflects the method correctly:

Version 1

```
int sigma1_iter(int n) {
  stack* s = create_stack(n);
  push(s, n);
  int res = 0;
  while(!is_empty(s)) {
    int elm = pop(s);
    if(elm == 0)
      return res;
    else {
      res += n;
      push(s, n-1);
    }
  }
}
```

Version 2

```
int sigma1_iter(int n) {
  stack* s = create_stack(n);
  push(s, n);
  int res = 0;
  while(!is_empty(s)) {
    if (n > 0) {
      n--;
      push(s, n);
    }
    else {
      int elm = pop(s);
      if(elm == 0)
        return res;
      else {
        res += n;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, in case of the tail recursive version of sigma with an accumulator:

```
int sigma2(int n, int res) {
  if (n == 0) 
    return res;
  else
    return sigma2(n-1, n+res);
}
```

How would one convert it? I am thinking of creating a second stack for res, but how that might work?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem and you're asking us to solve it for you. What do *you* think the answer is and why?

Comment: `create_stack(int n)` is not valid syntax. You put data types when declaring a function, not when calling it.

Comment: It is not a homework problem. `create_stack` is just a function I have that creates stack with memory allocation and so on

Comment: I don't care how it's defined, that's not how you call functions in C.

Comment: Assuming you fix the syntax, which one returns the correct result?

Comment: `void sigma1_iter(n)` is not correct syntax. You need the datatype before `n`. Why did you change this?

Comment: A `void` function can't return a value.

Comment: I think you should concentrate on learning C basics before you embark on this more advanced topic.

Comment: Sorry again, fixed (it's late for me and my brain is foggy). I have C basics, sorry,

Comment: The correct solution is to push all the numbers from n to 0 onto the stack. Then keep popping and adding them to the total until the stack is empty.

Comment: I see, so the idea is just to mimic the "recursive stack" that is behind recursion right?

Comment: I updated my question to ask about the tail version and the additional accumulator

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. Otherwise you could just use a `for` loop that adds to `res`.

Comment: Don't translate or convert  code, reimplement the *algorithm* instead.

Comment: Tail-recursion is equivalent to a `for` or `while` loop, it doesn't really use the stack.

Comment: Exactly that s what I was thinking, especially that the conversion method kind of brings the non tail recusrive function to a tail one iteratively if that makes sense.

Comment: I did implement the algorithm for version 2, but I read somewhere online and did the 1 one. That s why I am asking

Comment: @Barmar for quick sort for example with two recursive calls, I should have one stack pushing (start, end) ?

Comment: @Kim, Aside: avoid undefined behavior with `sigma1(-1)`.  Use something like `if (n <= 0) ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask a question. That helps everyone understand the question and generate and test potential answers.

If you had created such an example, it would be evident that version 1 of your iterative solution never returns and version 2 always returns 0 making neither a good candidate for correctness.

Recursion can be challenging, but I think we can walk through a general method for converting a recursive function to an iterative function for this example.

Let's look at the recursive implementation for `sigma1`,

```cpp
int sigma1(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return n + sigma1(n - 1);
}
```

Under the hood, calling this function generates a new stack frame for each recursive invocation (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it away). Each of these call frames will have the value of the argument `n` for that frame which will decrease by one at each level of recursion. We can think about the iterative version, in the same way, storing the value of `n` on our explicit `std::stack<int>` instead of it being handled automagically by the call stack.

When the recursion terminates and the call frames unwind, the local value of `n` is added to the result of the previous call creating a new result to be returned. In the same way, we can pop values from the explicit `std::stack<int>` and add them to the running total in the iterative version.

The function would look something like this,

```cpp
int sigma1_stack(int n) {
    std::stack<int> stack;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; --i)
        stack.push(i);

    int res{};
    while (not stack.empty()) {
        res += stack.top();
        stack.pop();
    }

    return res;
}
```

Now, in this particular scenario, you can simplify the two loops into a single iterative loop without a stack. This, of course, will not always be the case.

```cpp
int sigma1_iter(int n) {
    int res{};
    for (int i = n; i > 0; --i)
        res += i;
    return res;
}
```

I took the code you posted and changed it to compile using a `std::stack<int>` since you did not post a complete example. I also added a correct version of iteration for both `sigma1` and `sigma2` and the corresponding output. Hope this is helpful.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using std::cout, std::endl;

int sigma1(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return n + sigma1(n - 1);
}

int sigma1_iter_v1(int n) {
    std::stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(n);

    int res = 0;
    while (not stack.empty()) {
        int elm = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        if (elm == 0)
            return res;
        else {
            res += n;
            stack.push(n - 1);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int sigma1_iter_v2(int n) {
    std::stack<int> stack;
    stack.push(n);

    int res = 0;
    while (not stack.empty()) {
        if (n > 0) {
            n--;
            stack.push(n);
        } else {
            int elm = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            if(elm == 0)
                return res;
            else {
                res += n;
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int sigma1_iter(int n) {
    int res{};
    for (int i = n; i > 0; --i)
        res += i;
    return res;
}

int sigma1_stack(int n) {
    std::stack<int> stack;
    for (int i = n; i > 0; --i)
        stack.push(i);

    int res{};
    while (not stack.empty()) {
        res += stack.top();
        stack.pop();
    }

    return res;
}

int sigma2(int n, int res = 0) {
    if (n == 0)
        return res;
    else
        return sigma2(n - 1, n + res);
}

int sigma2_iter(int n) {
    int res{};
    for (int i = n; i > 0; --i)
        res += i;
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    cout << "sigma1         : " << sigma1(20) << endl;
    cout << "sigma1_iter   : " << sigma1_iter(20) << endl;
    cout << "sigma1_stack  : " << sigma1_stack(20) << endl;
    // This never returns
    // cout << "sigma1_iter_v1 : " << sigma1_iter_v1(20) << endl;
    cout << "sigma1_iter_v1 : " << "never returns" << endl;
    cout << "sigma1_iter_v2 : " << sigma1_iter_v2(20) << endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "sigma2         : " << sigma2(20) << endl;
    cout << "sigma2_iter    : " << sigma2_iter(20) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
sigma1         : 210
sigma1_iter    : 210
sigma1_stack   : 210
sigma1_iter_v1 : never returns
sigma1_iter_v2 : 0

sigma2         : 210
sigma2_iter    : 210
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to optimize your specific function, you can use the formula:
(n+1) * (n/2)

->

```
unsigned int sigma1(unsigned int n) {
  return (n+1) * (n/2);
}

unsigned int sigma2(unsigned int n, unsigned int res) {
  return (n+1) * (n/2) + res;
}
```

If you are just supporting unsigned numbers, I would just declare your function that way. Otherwise you would may encounter undefined behavior.